# 'NoClassdefFound' error while trying to use java keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, jython

I have Class B which contains a java method 'myJavaKeyword' which I wish to serve as robot framework keyword. This class B has imported class A from a jar file and being accessed in myJavaKeyword method of class B by creating object. I exported class B and called the library in my Robot test. I am getting 'NoClassDefFound' error for class A while executing my robot test.

The execution is getting successful if I export class B and class A in the same jar. But, if I make a separate jar for class A and put in jar of class B, I am getting this error. I need help in making the proper mapping between class A and class B for my situation.

My requirement exactly reflects the example I have given above.

```
package jarfile;
class A() {
public void method1() {
System.out.println("I created jar for this class and trying to access this method in class B")
}
}

package robotKeyword;
import jarfile.A;
class B 
{
public void myJavaKeyword() {

A obj = new A();
obj.method1();

System.out.println(" This is my Java keyword")
}
}


*** Settings ***
Library robotKeyword.B;

*** Testcase ***
Test custom keyword
      myJavaKeyword
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to get all the .jars on the classpath.

Comment: Class path of environment variables? Or Class path in red.xml? I tried both and did not work.

Comment: the class path in RED.

Comment: Thank you David and Kootstra. Adding classpath to red.xml worked to me.